# Ender 3 won't power up

Tags: creality-ender-3, power-supply, repair

I've had an Ender 3 for about a year and a half now and have been using it without issues.
Last week it turned off a few minutes into a print and wouldn't turn back on on power from the PSU. Connecting a laptop to the usb port does turn on the screen, which makes me think that the board should be fine.

Some investigation revealed that the glass fuse in the PSU power connection was blown.
I've replaced that and also ordered a replacement PSU, but the printer still won't turn on.
The PSU is outputting 24 V, I've tested that with a multimeter and attached a picture.

[image: Multimeter reading]

I'd be very grateful for any further hints as far as debugging this issue goes. I feel like the next step might be buying a new mainboard and testing with that, but I want to make sure I'm not missing anything obvious.

Comment: Hi welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! There must be a cause that spiked the PSU to cause the glass fuse to fail. It could be that you have more damage from that further down the line; i.e. the controller board. Replacing the board would be my preferred solution.

Comment: If you're going to get a new controller board, you might want to look at some reviews of the BigTreeTech boards. Just in case you feel like an upgrade at the same time, and that's half the fun of a 3-d printer for some people.

Comment: @0scar Thanks for the welcome. 
I feel the same way that there must be some other problem that I'm missing, which is the only thing holding me back from just sticking a new board in. 
I am looking at getting a BigTreeTech board to upgrade, but I was wondering if there's anywhere else to measure/ check for what might have caused the problem in the first place.